# Javascript refactroing series of if else statement

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I have a method and attached an event listener like below.

This method looks ugly. Is there any other way to refactor?

Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.

```
document.querySelector('dateInput').addEventListener('input', func.validateCalendar, false);
```

```
const func = {
validateCalendar({target}){
        const tmpArr = Array.from(target.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
        
        if( tmpArr.length === 0 ){
            
            target.value = '';
            
        }else if( tmpArr.length === 4){
            
            target.value = tmpArr.join('');
            
        }else if( tmpArr.length === 5 ){ //month first digit 
        
            const month1 = +tmpArr[4]
        
            console.log('len:5, month1: ', month1);
                
            if( month1 > 1 ){
                tmpArr.splice(4,1, '');
            }
            
            tmpArr.splice(4,0, '-');
            
            target.value = tmpArr.join('');
            
        }else if( tmpArr.length === 6){ //month second digit 
            const month1 = +tmpArr[4];
            const month2 = +tmpArr[5];
            
            const cond1 = month1 === 0 && month2 === 0;
            const cond2 = month1 === 0 && month2 > 9;
            const cond3 = month1 === 1 && month2 > 2
            
            if( cond1 || cond2 || cond3 ){
                tmpArr.splice(5,1, '');
            }
            
            tmpArr.splice(4,0, '-');
            
            target.value = tmpArr.join('');
        }else if( tmpArr.length === 7 ){ //day first digit 
            const month = +tmpArr.slice(4,6).join('');
            const day1 = +tmpArr[6];
            
            console.log('len 7 : day1 ', day1);
            
            const cond1 = month !== 2 && day1 > 3;
            const cond2 = month === 2 && day1 > 2
            
            if( cond1 || cond2 ){
                tmpArr.splice(6,1, '');
            }
            
            tmpArr.splice(4,0, '-')
            tmpArr.splice(7,0, '-');
            
            target.value = tmpArr.join('');
            
        }else if( tmpArr.length === 8 ){ //day second digit 
            
            const year = +tmpArr.slice(1,4).join('');
            
            const month = +tmpArr.slice(4,6).join('');
            
            const day = +tmpArr.slice(6,8).join('');
            
            const monthsIn31 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12];
            const monthsIn30 = [4, 6, 9, 11];
            
            const cond1 = day === 0;
            const cond2 = monthsIn31.includes(month) && day > 31;
            const cond3 = monthsIn30.includes(month) && day > 30;
            const cond4 = month === 2;
            
            if( cond1 || cond2 || cond3){
                tmpArr.splice(7,1, '');
            }
            
            if( cond4 ){
                const cond1 = moment([year]).isLeapYear() && day > 29;
                const cond2 = !moment([year]).isLeapYear() && day > 28
                if( cond1 || cond2 ){
                    tmpArr.splice(7,1, '');
                }
            }
            console.log('len 8 : ', target.value);
            
            tmpArr.splice(4,0, '-')
            tmpArr.splice(7,0, '-');
            
            target.value = tmpArr.join('');
        }else if( tmpArr.length > 8 ){
            target.value = target.value.slice(0, -1);
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: Try using switch case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `switch..case` if you just check a variable again and again.

Thus if you currently have:

```js
var a = 5
if(a === 5){
  console.log("Five");

} else if(a === 7) {
  console.log("Seven");

} else if (a === 9) {
  console.log("Nine");

} 

// ... and so on

else {
  console.log("Irrelevant");
}
```

This is equivalent `switch..case` for it

```js
var a = 5

switch(a) {
  case 5:
    console.log("Five");
    break;
  
  case 7:
    console.log("Seven");
    break;
  
// ... and so on

  default:
    console.log("Irrelevant");
  
}
```

However, meanwhile the `if..else if` uses curly brackets `{}` to limit the scope of the condition, `switch..case` uses `break` to limit it. The `default` in the `switch..case` is equivalent to the `else` in `if..else`, if and only if you put the `break` properly.

If you forget to put `break`, it will execute every cases placed under the satisfied condition until it finds the `break` or `return` or the `default` or the closing curly bracket `}` of the `switch..case` statement.